# How to deduce the results of response time by this trajectory approach?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, recursive-algorithms

First, we denote this:
[image]
[image]
And

And we get this right property( $last_i$ means the last node on $τ_i$):
[image]

And:
 $Smin_i^h$ = $\sum_{h'=first_i}^{h-1} ({C_i^{h'} + L_{max})}$

$Smax_i^h$ = $W_{i,t}^{h-1}$ + $C_i^{h-1}$ + $L_{max}$

In this case, the values are simple:
$C_i^h$ = *4*, for all values of $i$ or $h$.
$L_{max}$ = $L_{min}$ = *1*.
$T_{i}$ = *36*, for all values of $i$.
$J_i$ = *0*, for all values of $i$.
{$τ_1$, $τ_2$, ... , $τ_n$}, the set of all flows.
$n$ = *5*, the total number of flows.

And the flows are defined as:

$\begin{align}
&\bullet\,\,\, \mathcal P_1=\{1,3,4,5\}\quad &\quad&\bullet\,\,\,\mathcal P_2=\{9,10,7,6\} \\
&\bullet\,\,\, \mathcal P_3=\{2,3,4,7,10,11\}\quad &\quad&\bullet\,\,\,\mathcal P_4=\{2,3,4,7,10,11\} \\
&\bullet\,\,\,\mathcal P_5=\{2,3,4,7,8\}. 
\end{align}$

And $R_1$ to $R_5$ corresponding to $\tau_1$ to $\tau_5$ are:

$\displaystyle\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \tau_1 & \tau_2 & \tau_3 & \tau_4 & \tau_5 \\
\hline 31 & 43 & 53 & 53 & 44 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

**So how to deduce the results?**

Comment: Delete the image and  type it mannuaaly.The fig font sucks.

Comment: You can get the whole details here: https://www2.lirmm.fr/lirmm/interne/BIBLI/CDROM/MIC/2006/IPDPS_2006/IPDPS06/pdfs/137-WPDRTS-paper-1.pdf

Comment: @exploringnet: it would be nicer to ask, "Would it be possible to replace the image with MathJax? The image is hard to read."

Comment: @exploringnet,see this link https://www2.lirmm.fr/lirmm/interne/BIBLI/CDROM/MIC/2006/IPDPS_2006/IPDPS06/pdfs/137-WPDRTS-paper-1.pdf